# Electric Circuits and Kirchhoff's Voltage Law

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage

Assume we have a circuit containing a voltage source and two resistors connected in parallel.
If I assume one resistor is shorter than the other and they "start at the same height" then their potential change can't be the same due to the definition of voltage
\begin{equation*}
V(a) - V(b) = \int_a^b \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{s}.
\end{equation*}
So where is my mistake? Are there certain differences between real circuits and circuit models which result in both resistors having the same voltage?

Comment: The electric field inside the shorter resistor is larger.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage, in the sense of potential difference (potential drop when going from $a$ to $b$) $\varphi_a - \varphi_b$, can be expressed as integral of the conservative part of electric field:

$$
\varphi_a - \varphi_b = \int_a^b \mathbf E_C \cdot d\mathbf s,
$$

but it does not depend on the path of integration, only on the endpoints $a,b$. This is because of the conservativeness of the field $\mathbf E_C$.

It does not matter that two different resistors connect their terminals (allowing electric conduction) to the same two points; the integral above along any path from point $a$ to point $b$ is the same, including paths through both resistors. If one resistor is shorter, then this will be compensated by stronger field $\mathbf E_C$ inside that resistor so the integral is the same.

Comment: And why is the E stronger? The charge which defines E should be the same right? My only guess is it has something to do with (1/r^2)

Comment: E is stronger in shorter resistor because the integral has the same value, and the path is shorter. This is possible because charge distribution on terminals of the shorter resistor is different than on the longer resistor. On the shorter resistor terminals there is more charge, making the electric field stronger there.

Comment: Ok, thats right but  we are defining E in this kontext by means of the charge of your electric Field generated by the voltage source, arent we? Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: In the Kirchhoff voltage law we have potential differences, which are defined through the conservative part of the electric field, $\mathbf E_C$. This field is due to electric charges on the voltage source, on the wires, and other components in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the resistors are made of the same material and the only difference is their length, $d$ and $2d$.

[image]

Minus the work done by the electric field in moving unit positive charge from node $a$ to node $b$ is the potential difference across the resistors.

$\displaystyle \int^{\rm b}_{\rm a} E\,ds = -E_1\,d = -\dfrac Vd\,d = \mathbf{-V} = V_{\rm b} - V_{\rm a} =0-V = \mathbf{-V}$

$\displaystyle \int^{\rm b}_{\rm a} E\,ds = -E_2\,2d = -\dfrac {V}{2d}\,2d = \mathbf{-V} = V_{\rm b} - V_{\rm a} =0-V = \mathbf{-V}$

Thus the work done is path independent as one might expect as the electric field is conservative.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting there now. So we assume there is only a potential difference in the resistors because we are assuming the remaining conductors have zero resistance, right?
If we talk about the potential differnece of resistors connected in parallel we are integrating from the same Beginning to the same End, hope I am getting this correctly.

Comment: Yes, the same start and the same finish and independent of the path taken.